# rpm can't be installed on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation

I cant install rpm on Ubuntu 14.04 
I used this series of commands

```
sudo apt-get install alien dpkg-dev debhelper build-essential
sudo alien packagename.rpm
sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb
```

and I get this error:

```
File "packagename.rpm" not found
```

Comment: From where have you downloaded packagename.rpm. and is it downloaded to current directory ?

Comment: i am in the home directory and i am fresh on linux and i use the seriese of the commands above thank you for responding

Comment: You will have to download the .rpm file(s) from somewhere. They are not in any Ubuntu repository, nor do they appear by magic.

Comment: i just did what is written in this website http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-install-an-rpm-package-on-ubuntu-linux  and it didn't work

Comment: No, as I write, you will have to download the .rpm from somewhere. What application are you trying to install ?

Comment: good morning my friend , i cant find where to install .rpm every website keeps giving me the same instruction and the result is always  File "package-name.rpm" not found.

Comment: Try to answer the question from my first comment `From where have you downloaded packagename.rpm. and is it downloaded to current directory ?`. Then maybe someone can help you.